# raspberry pi 4 red and green light solid

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, sd-card

current problem with raspberry pi 4 4GB,

raspberry pi 4 red and green light solid - with SD Card plugged in - Raspian OS installed.

When i use the SD Card recovery the green light turns off with the red light remaining?

But when i reinstall Raspian OS with the SD Card and boot the solid green light returns

I assume it is an SD card problem but have tried others and the problem remains.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: What is this "Raspian OS"? If you can't even get the OS name right you don't inspire confidence so we don't know what you have or have done.

Comment: According to some of the forums, this has been a pernicious problem with some RPi 4s. You might try [reviewing this post](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=250183) for some clues - it's quite lengthy as it's been going on for 4 years!

Comment: What is this "SD Card recovery"?

Comment: Did it ever work? What do you see on your monitor?

Comment: @Milliways: RE *"What is this "Raspian OS"? "* Give it a break, please. `lsb_release -d` ==> Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye). I suppose if the folks that make RPi still refer to their OS as Raspbian, then it must really be Raspbian.

Comment: What is your question?